# Capistrano 3 "upload" task raises error

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I have capistrano 3 task

```
namespace :db do
  desc "serurely manages dbconn file after deploy"
  task :dbconfig do
    on roles(:web) do |host|
      upload("config/deploy/dbconn.template.php", "#{shared_path}/dbconn.php")
    end
  end
end
```

When running 
`cap staging db:dbconfig`
I get error

```
   cap aborted!
   undefined method `upload' for #<SSHKit::Backend::Netssh:0x007ffe9a84b9f8>
```

According to capistrano API I can use this method to upload files, i also found it in source code of sshkit lib

gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (1.3.5)
capistrano (3.0.1)
CFPropertyList (2.2.0)
i18n (0.6.5)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
net-scp (1.1.2)
net-ssh (2.7.0)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
rake (10.1.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
sshkit (1.1.0)
term-ansicolor (1.2.2)
tins (0.13.1)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears the method is called `upload!`: https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#upload-a-file-from-disk

Where did you see it badly documented, maybe you could send them a pull request to fix their docs?

Comment: Thanx, Lee. It happened that method must be called as upload! to be invoked in right way, you were right. However, they've got much more important things to document. Thank you for help

Comment: I'm the author of cap/sshkit. I always appreciate PRS for docs and issues for things you need docimented

Comment: It used to be called `upload` in Capistrano 2 so maybe that's the confusion.